# Maven plugin to test i18n properties

Tags: maven, plugins, internationalization, automated-tests, properties-file

does anybody know a maven plugin that tests all my language properties files? I want to test that every language in my project contains all keys.

Use cases:

- Figure out if so. added a key to the default file and forgot to add to any of the other language files.
- Figure out if so. dropped a key in one of the files and forgot to drop it in all the other files.

It is not that difficult to write my own small maven plugin, but I would prefer an already existing one. Haven't found one so far.

Or: How do you test your files? Manually / automated / not at all?

Eric

Answer (score 1):

You should give a try to the [i18n-maven-plugin](http://i18n.nuiton.org/v/develop/en/i18n-maven-plugin/index.html). In the build (process-resources phase), all your Java classes, JSP will be parsed to find all the i18n keys in your project (according to your pom).

The plugin will add all the i18n keys that are missing in all you bundles. There is also a [strict mode](http://i18n.nuiton.org/v/develop/en/i18n-maven-plugin/parserJava-mojo.html#strictMode) that remove all the i18n keys that are no longer found in your application from your bundles so you can be sure that 100% of the keys are both used in your app and translated in every language.

For a working, real-life example, feel free to check out this application:

```
svn checkout https://svn.codelutin.com/wao/tags/wao-4.0.4/
mvn clean process-resources -Di18n.verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny - I gave my project the same name a couple of years ago. https://github.com/hoereth/i18n-maven-plugin

This plugin serves me well on numerous projects. It turns around the concept of properties files 180 degrees. **You maintain a well structured XMl file with your translations and the plugin will create all properties files for you during build time.** No need for validation at his point. It can also create a Java class which holds all translation keys - thus enabling you to compile-check your translation calls.

Believe me - this takes away the pain of translating from a technical point of view. :)